# Why are my jQuery widgets oversized?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, widget

As you can see in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/755nK/), the datepicker popup is very large in comparison to the one on the [Themeroller page](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/#ffDefault=Segoe+UI,+Arial,+sans-serif&fwDefault=bold&fsDefault=1.1em&cornerRadius=6px&bgColorHeader=333333&bgTextureHeader=12_gloss_wave.png&bgImgOpacityHeader=25&borderColorHeader=333333&fcHeader=ffffff&iconColorHeader=ffffff&bgColorContent=000000&bgTextureContent=05_inset_soft.png&bgImgOpacityContent=25&borderColorContent=666666&fcContent=ffffff&iconColorContent=cccccc&bgColorDefault=555555&bgTextureDefault=02_glass.png&bgImgOpacityDefault=20&borderColorDefault=666666&fcDefault=eeeeee&iconColorDefault=cccccc&bgColorHover=0078a3&bgTextureHover=02_glass.png&bgImgOpacityHover=40&borderColorHover=59b4d4&fcHover=ffffff&iconColorHover=ffffff&bgColorActive=f58400&bgTextureActive=05_inset_soft.png&bgImgOpacityActive=30&borderColorActive=ffaf0f&fcActive=ffffff&iconColorActive=222222&bgColorHighlight=eeeeee&bgTextureHighlight=03_highlight_soft.png&bgImgOpacityHighlight=80&borderColorHighlight=cccccc&fcHighlight=2e7db2&iconColorHighlight=4b8e0b&bgColorError=ffc73d&bgTextureError=02_glass.png&bgImgOpacityError=40&borderColorError=ffb73d&fcError=111111&iconColorError=a83300&bgColorOverlay=5c5c5c&bgTextureOverlay=01_flat.png&bgImgOpacityOverlay=50&opacityOverlay=80&bgColorShadow=cccccc&bgTextureShadow=01_flat.png&bgImgOpacityShadow=30&opacityShadow=60&thicknessShadow=7px&offsetTopShadow=-7px&offsetLeftShadow=-7px&cornerRadiusShadow=8px) for the same theme. This happens with other widgets like dialogs.

If you look at the resources panel you'll see that I've linked to unmodified Google-hosted css and js files, so I haven't done anything to the files.. how can I get my widgets to display nicely like the ones on the Themeroller page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
.ui-widget {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

The default `font-size` of the jquery-ui themeroller is **10px**, the `.ui-widget` CSS property comes with `font-size:1.1em`, and `.ui-datepicker` table comes after with `font-size:0.9em`.

To conclude, the font-size of your jquery-ui widgets depends on your default CSS font-size.

Comment: I knew it was just some CSS override, but didn't know what to replace :P Thanks for explaining it!

Answer (score 1):

Add  `.ui-widget { font-size: 0.6em; }​` and it should solve your problem.